# How to add a new normally distributed data column based on the exsiting paramter columns in a dataframe in r?

Tags: r, dataframe, list, normal-distribution, sapply

I want to generate a new column(for every single cell is a list of data)) called 'val', which is a normally distributed data, based on the exsiting columns in R. However it returns error as follows:
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, val, value = c(0.771570544918682, 0.203569004424465,  :
replacement has 6 rows, data has 3. Need help. I doubt have used the wrong function.

Any hint or tip would be apprciated. Thanks.

```
df <- data.frame(n1 = c(5, 10, 20), 
n2 = c(10, 10, 20), 
m1 = c(0.01, 1.2, 1.1), 
m2 = c(0.1,0.2,0.5), 
sd1 = c(1,1,1), 
sd2 = c(2,1,2))

df$val <- sapply(df, function(x) 
c(rnorm(df$n1, df$m1, df$sd1), rnorm(df$n2, df$m2, df$sd2)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to use `purrr::pmap`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>% 
  mutate(val=pmap(list(n1,n2,m1,m2,sd1,sd2),
                  function(n1,n2,m1,m2,sd1,sd2) c(rnorm(n1,m1,sd1),rnorm(n2,m2,sd2))))
```

Comment: Thank you, peter861222. It works well. Good to learn.

Answer (score 0):

You can go row by row and using `lapply` and `with`.

```
df$val <- lapply(seq_len(nrow(df)), \(i) with(df[i,],
                 c(rnorm(n1, m1, sd1), rnorm(n2, m2, sd2))) )
```

Comment: Thank you, GKi. It also works well. Can you tell me more about what does \(i) with(df[i,] mean?

Comment: `with` *evaluates an R expression in an environment constructed from data.*